# List view like a document

Tags: 2007, infopath, list-view

I have a huge form in sharepoint 2007 i made in infopath that was originally a paper form the client would still like to view it like the paper form.

Is their anyway to make a view that looks more like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPdxS.jpg for each individual entry?

Thanks

Lewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to design a data view webpart that has that as it's default view. The data can be rearranged in a table so that it mimics the form that you provided. Each table cell can have data of the form in it, and you can massage the form and insert the data anywhere on the page in the table, matching the form.

Here is how you can set up the dataview webpart to get you started:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-extending-the-dvwp-part-1-layout-enhancement-rearranging-columns-default-and-edit-templates.aspx